# Split a single variable out to many and call them separatly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to produce estimated walking and driving times based on a distance.

```
function handleMeasurements(event) {
var geometry = event.geometry;
var units = event.units;
var order = event.order;
var measure = event.measure;
var measure_corrected = measure / 1.67;
var element = document.getElementById('output');
var out = "";

// Walking time from distance.
var walking_time_mins = (((measure_corrected / 4) * 60).toFixed(2));
var minutes = (walking_time_mins % 60);
var hours = (walking_time_mins - minutes)/60;   


if(order == 1) {
out += "measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "Walking time (hh.mm.ss)" + hours + "." +  minutes;
      } else {
out += "measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup>";
}
element.innerHTML = out;
}
```

This code is in a .js file and on the html page the 'var out;' variable is called by `<div id="output"></div>`.
Everything is working fine but the 'var out;' result is all on one line. I would like to divide `"measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units +"` and `"Walking time (hh.mm.ss)" + hours + "." +  minutes;"` into different cells in a table. I got a lot of this code from examples on the internet and I can't figure out how `<div id="output"></div>` knows to call 'var out;'. It doesn't seem to be connected anywhere. Can anybody offer any advise on how to split 'var out;' into different variables and how to call them separately in a html page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the key was the getElementID tag.

```
function handleMeasurements(event) {
            var geometry = event.geometry;
            var units = event.units;
            var order = event.order;
            var measure = event.measure;
            var measure_corrected = measure / 1.67;
            var wtime = document.getElementById('walking_time');
            var dtime = document.getElementById('driving_time')
            var element = document.getElementById('output');

            var out = "";
            var out_time = "";
            var out_drive = "";

            // Walking time from distance.
            var walking_time_mins = (((measure_corrected / 4) * 60).toFixed(2));
            var minutes = (walking_time_mins % 60);
            var minutes_corrected = (minutes).toFixed(2);
            var hours = (walking_time_mins - minutes)/60;   

            // Driving time from distance.
            //var driving_time_mins = (((measure_corrected / 30) * 60).toFixed(2));


            if(order == 1) {
                out += measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units;  
                out_time +=  "(hh.mm.ss)" + hours + "." +  minutes_corrected;
            } else {
            out += "measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup>";
            }


            element.innerHTML = out;
            wtime.innerHTML = out_time;

}
```

And here is the html table code;

```
<table class="WDTime" align="left">
  <tr><th>Distance:</th><td id="output"></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Walking time:</th><td id="walking_time"></td></tr>
  <tr><th>Driving time:</th><td id="driving_time"></td></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try replacing below

```
if(order == 1) {
out += "measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "Walking time (hh.mm.ss)" + hours + "." +  minutes;
      } else {
out += "measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup>";
}
```

with

```
out="<table><tr>";
if(order == 1) {
out += "<td>measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "</td><td>Walking time (hh.mm.ss)" + hours + "." +  minutes+"</td>";
      } else {
out += "<td colspan=2>measure: " + measure_corrected.toFixed(3) + " " + units + "<sup>2</" + "sup></td>";
}
out+="</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply Nishesh, I had tried something like that. Ideally I would like to have it so it populated cells in a table separately. If I could figure out how var = out; and div id="output" are linked it would solve the problem, I think.

Comment: Can you provide the GUI part for that? It will be easy to understand then what you are sating.

Comment: I think it related to this code `var element = document.getElementById('output', 'walking_time');`